# Dimensionality reduction for low correlating data

Tags: correlation, dimensionality-reduction

Are there any good methods to perform dimensionality reduction on data where most features lack distinct correlation?

Comment: If you don't see *linear* correlation, that doesn't mean there is no correlation of any sorts between features at all. Could you edit your question to clarify what kind of correlation you mean?

Comment: Universal manifold approximation and projection (UMAP) caught my eye a few months ago, and I looked forward to getting a project where I can use it (haven’t been doing predictive modeling lately): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#Uniform_manifold_approximation_and_projection. That whole Wikipedia article has ideas, assuming, to which @FransRodenburg alludes, that you have nonlinear “correlation” (dependence in general) amongst your variables. // What about penalized regression like elastic net? Then you don’t lose features, you just dampen their effects.